# how to display the text message inside the fontawesome square icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

this my code.how to show text message inside the square box with size 1x.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x" style="margin-left:5%">
 <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>   
</span>
```

[image: this is my fontawesome square box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put position absolute and put margin as per your requirement on the div tag you create in which you put the text.

```
<div style="position: absolute;">asdasdaddas</div>
```

Comment: the text displayed but not size fixed with in square box

Answer (score 1):

Let the Font Awesome classes do the work. Wrap your text in the `fa-stack-1x` class and it will position and center it over the icon. You can play with the font size from there if needed.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <span class="fa fa-stack-1x">Aa</span>
</span>
```

http://jsbin.com/pisadulufo/1/edit?html,css,output